# Validating datetime field with FormHelper validation

Tags: php, cakephp

One of my tables has a field called `created` which is a `datetime` data type. I have a view set up to add new entries which looks like this:

```
<h1>Compose post</h1>

<?php echo $this->Form->create('Post'); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('title'); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('body'); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('created'); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('slug'); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->end('Publish'); ?>
```

The `created` field comes out looking like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQG4q.png

Now, I'm insure how I go about writing a validation rule for this. I tried using CakePHP's `datetime` validation rule like so:

```
'created' => array(
    'format' => array(
        'rule' => array('datetime', 'Mdy'),
        'message' => 'A valid date and time in Mdy format'
    )
)
```

but it doesn't work. The [CakePHP documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html#Validation%3a%3adatetime) is also a little confusing on the subject.

So, how can I properly validate a datetime field?

Comment: `created` is [automagically generated](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#using-created-and-modified), you shouldn't need to validate it. If you want to do it manually for some reason, see that link

Comment: Woops, forgot about that. If you make that an answer instead of a comment I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 0):

Normally the 'created' field is just a field that's added to the table, then automatically generated by CakePHP.  (same goes for the 'modified' field - both are DATETIME)

If that's what you want, just remove it's field and allow Cake to do it's thing.  No need for validation.

If you do want to validate a date like that though, I believe you have to first combine it into a single string instead of an array (easy enough to do with PHP just before the save), which is what those form fields will submit.

Answer (score 0):

well the way it worked for me was like this

```
'created' => array(
        'rule' => array('datetime'), 
        'required' => true,
        'message' => 'Enter Valid creation date'
)
```